# Generate new observations based on IF statement R

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

Below you can find a sample of my data. My goal is to create new observations based on my Outtime variable. I would like to create 1 extra observation if Outtime equals Pre or Post, and 2 extra observations if Outtime equals PrePost.

```
   ID Hospital Room           StartDate             EndDate Type             StartDT               EndDT Outtime
1 101     ODCC  4SW 2020-06-04 16:21:47 2020-06-22 15:12:39 <NA>                <NA>                <NA>    <NA>
2 101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-08-13 23:59:58 PrePost
3 101     ODCC   1N 2020-09-08 14:03:35 2020-11-02 06:50:24   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-10-13 23:59:58    Post
4 101     ODCC  1WH 2020-11-02 06:50:25 2021-02-05 14:25:54   ER 2020-08-01 00:00:02 2021-05-13 23:59:58    <NA>
```

Below is what I would like to have.  Thank you!

```
   ID Hospital Room           StartDate             EndDate Type             StartDT               EndDT Outtime
1 101     ODCC  4SW 2020-06-04 16:21:47 2020-06-22 15:12:39 <NA>                <NA>                <NA>    <NA>
2 101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-08-13 23:59:58 PrePost
2 101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-08-13 23:59:58 PrePost
2 101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-08-13 23:59:58 PrePost
3 101     ODCC   1N 2020-09-08 14:03:35 2020-11-02 06:50:24   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-10-13 23:59:58    Post
3 101     ODCC   1N 2020-09-08 14:03:35 2020-11-02 06:50:24   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-10-13 23:59:58    Post
4 101     ODCC  1WH 2020-11-02 06:50:25 2021-02-05 14:25:54   ER 2020-08-01 00:00:02 2021-05-13 23:59:58    <NA>
```

Data sample

```
structure(list(ID = c(101, 101, 101, 101), Hospital = c("ODCC", 
"ODCC", "ODCC", "ODCC"), Room = c("4SW", "1W", "1N", "1WH"), 
    StartDate = structure(c(1591287707, 1592838760, 1599573815, 
    1604299825), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    EndDate = structure(c(1592838759, 1599573814, 1604299824, 
    1612535154), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Type = c(NA, "ER", "ER", "ER"), StartDT = structure(c(NA, 
    1593561602, 1593561602, 1596240002), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), EndDT = structure(c(NA, 1597363198, 1602633598, 
    1620950398), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), Outtime = c(NA, "PrePost", "Post", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: You can't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy approach using base R might be:

```
rbind(df,
      subset(df, Outtime == "Post"),
      subset(df, Outtime == "PrePost"),
      subset(df, Outtime == "PrePost")
)
```

Here you use `rbind` to combine rows, where you add rows by subsetting your original data frame additional times.

Another approach might be the following. Create a column that includes the number of times a row should be repeated. Then, you can include rows multiple times from your data frame repeating `rep` the number of times indicated with the new column.

```
df$Times <- factor(df$Outtime,
                   exclude = NULL,
                   levels = c(NA, "Post", "PrePost"),
                   labels = 1:3)

df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Times), ]
```

**Output**

```
    ID Hospital Room           StartDate             EndDate Type             StartDT               EndDT Outtime
1  101     ODCC  4SW 2020-06-04 16:21:47 2020-06-22 15:12:39 <NA>                <NA>                <NA>    <NA>
2  101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-08-13 23:59:58 PrePost
3  101     ODCC   1N 2020-09-08 14:03:35 2020-11-02 06:50:24   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-10-13 23:59:58    Post
4  101     ODCC  1WH 2020-11-02 06:50:25 2021-02-05 14:25:54   ER 2020-08-01 00:00:02 2021-05-13 23:59:58    <NA>
31 101     ODCC   1N 2020-09-08 14:03:35 2020-11-02 06:50:24   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-10-13 23:59:58    Post
21 101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-08-13 23:59:58 PrePost
22 101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-08-13 23:59:58 PrePost
```

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up using the rbind option!

Answer (score 0):

Use `uncount`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% left_join(data.frame(Outtime = c('Pre', 'Post', 'PrePost'),
                            dummy = c(2, 2, 3)), by = 'Outtime') %>% 
  mutate(dummy = replace(dummy, is.na(dummy), 1)) %>%
  uncount(dummy)

   ID Hospital Room           StartDate             EndDate Type             StartDT               EndDT Outtime
1 101     ODCC  4SW 2020-06-04 16:21:47 2020-06-22 15:12:39 <NA>                <NA>                <NA>    <NA>
2 101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-08-13 23:59:58 PrePost
3 101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-08-13 23:59:58 PrePost
4 101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-08-13 23:59:58 PrePost
5 101     ODCC   1N 2020-09-08 14:03:35 2020-11-02 06:50:24   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-10-13 23:59:58    Post
6 101     ODCC   1N 2020-09-08 14:03:35 2020-11-02 06:50:24   ER 2020-07-01 00:00:02 2020-10-13 23:59:58    Post
7 101     ODCC  1WH 2020-11-02 06:50:25 2021-02-05 14:25:54   ER 2020-08-01 00:00:02 2021-05-13 23:59:58    <NA>
```